# Installing QGIS Statist plugin in Mac OS X?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, mac

I'm trying to install the Statist plugin.  I'm running MacOSX 10.7.5. with Python 2.7.3. and Numpy 1.5.1.

I have also installed matplotlib 1.1.0 (for python 2.7).  When I try to install the Statist 1.0.0 plugin, I get an error message saying that I need matplotlib installed. Somehow QGIS is not finding it.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using and how did you install matplotlib btw?

Answer (score 3):

It is always the same problem of PATH: the QGIS version of Kyngchaos uses exclusively the standard Python installed in Mac OS X and not those installed from Python.org, with Homebrew, MacPorts or Fink, see my answer in [QGIS Python version](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/qgis-python-version/51911#51911).

Answer (score 2):

You can try Fink version of QGIS.  It recognizes python modules installed by Fink.  Another reason I recommend Fink is I am the maintainer of QGIS for Fink. ;-p

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [KyngChaos build of Matplotlib](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python) and see if it works.