# Changing Python Version in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have installed ImageMagick via Homebrew and apparently it's within Python 3.8 but my QGIS is using Python 3.7.3. Therefore, it's telling me that I don't have ImageMagick installed (and therefore won't do what I want to do, which is to export an animated GIF using the TimeManager plugin). I'm running OS 10.15.4, QGIS 3.12.2. everything patched up.

How do I tell QGIS to use Python 3.8 and not 3.7?

I am not a programmer and do not understand what it means to have "ImageMagick installed in Path". I'm assuming it's the path of the version of Python that QGIS is using.  I don't really understand the instruction on [ImageMagick web](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question and it looks like you need to install QGIS I'm Homebrew if you want it to use the Python in Homebrew. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/setting-qgis-python-version

Comment: @BrianZ this is not a duplicate question. I mentioned homebrew merely to give information on where/how I installed ImageMagick.

Comment: @BrianZ. PS. I have seen the post you linked. It is relevant but it doesn't answer my question (plus, that post is from 7 years ago)

Comment: Is it the case that QGIS is installed directly but ImageMagick is installed with Homebrew? If so, what I take from that old answer is this is why they are looking for Python in different places. If you already installed QGIS via homebrew then nevermind, but check your `/etc/paths`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround, so use the external tools to create animations from image series.

This feature has been removed in the latest version. The plugin has been deprecated from QGIS version 3.14 in favor of built-in temporal support