# QGIS 2.0 won't open on OSX Mavericks

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, osx

I successfully installed QGIS 2.0 on my macbook running OSX Mavericks, but when I attempt to open the program, I get the following message:  "QGIS cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer and make sure QGIS works with this version of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and OS X."

As far as I can tell, everything is updated and I reinstalled QGIS twice with no luck.

Problem details and system configuration:
Process:         QGIS [1087]
Path:            /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Identifier:      org.qgis.qgis2
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [132]
Responsible:     QGIS [1087]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-01-06 17:36:06.120 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  FC49D1E1-1069-09AE-FE37-E5ADF06A6277

Sleep/Wake UUID: 03863BF4-29D6-4A54-A415-DD0D62750EEF

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Versions/4/PROJ
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
  Reason: Incompatible library version: QGIS requires version 8.0.0 or later, but PROJ provides version 7.0.0

Binary Images:
    0x7fff6b7f7000 -     0x7fff6b82a817  dyld (239.3)  /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff87216000 -     0x7fff87280ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.1 - 907.1.13)  /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff8f37e000 -     0x7fff8f37efff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <3E3F01A8-314D-378F-835E-9CC4F8820031> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff90e77000 -     0x7fff9105cff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.11)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation

Model: MacBook5,1, BootROM MB51.007D.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.32f8
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142323837344448312D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142323837344448312D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK2553GSX, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-868
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:

Comment: Welcome on GIS SE. Please check first if http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44393/how-to-install-the-qgis-statist-plugin-in-mac-os-x does not contain the answer to your question

Comment: You dylib error indicates you may have upgraded a Kyngchaos.com QGIS install and not upgraded its [underlying GDAL and GSL frameworks](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks). GDAL Complete framework must be the latest 1.10, and GSL helps with some aspects of the georeferencer plugin. Besides Python modules (psycopg, numpy), those are the only frameworks now required. (Btw, this is all in the Kyngchaos installs' READMEs.)

Answer (score 1):

I've just set up QGIS 2.0 on Mavericks, rather than upgraded, but see no reason why the process would be any different.

KyngChaos maintains the Mac version of QGIS (linked to from the QGIS site in case you're worried).

You need FreeType for Matplotlib. Ensure you download and install that first: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks

You can then download Matplotlib python module from from: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python

Let me know if that works or if you still receive errors.

Comment: Installing Matplotlib worked, thanks! Unfortunately, after installing QGIS 2.0, I get an error when trying to open the program (see my modified post above)

Comment: @user25471 - Try reinstalling the latest version of the GDAL framework from KyngChaos. Make sure you use version 1.10 (the present latest version). You may need to uninstall QGIS before updating the framework, then reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried reinstalling Python numerous times

Why ?

Python is installed in Mac OS X (look my answers in [QGIS Python version](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/qgis-python-version/51911#51911))

The only thing you need is, as [radouxju](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25070/radouxju) says, to install the [matplotlib](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python) version of KyngChaos or other version of matplotlib, as long  as the name of the resulting folder is matplotlib in the site-packages of the Apple Python (in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages, where numpy is installed: numpy-override folder)